# node app getting killed frequently with npm err

Tags: node.js, express, npm, graphql, apollo-server

Upgraded the node to 16.4.2 and npm to 8.5.0&8.5.5 and I started getting errors randomly and bringing the app down. I  tried reverting the version but the errors still happen.

```
0 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
1 info using npm@8.5.5
2 info using node@v16.14.2
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/cl-app/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 5ms
11 timing config:load:file:/root/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 7ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 7ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 2ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 24ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 24ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
22 timing npm:load:display Completed in 3ms
23 verbose logfile /root/.npm/_logs/2022-03-28T17_05_19_156Z-debug-0.log
24 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 5ms
25 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
27 timing npm:load Completed in 35ms
28 timing command:run-script Completed in 307342ms
29 timing command:start Completed in 307344ms
30 verbose stack Error: command failed
30 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
30 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
30 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
30 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
31 verbose pkgid chapp@0.0.0
32 verbose cwd /cl-app
33 verbose Linux 4.14.231-173.360.amzn2.x86_64
34 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
35 verbose node v16.14.2
36 verbose npm  v8.5.5
37 error path /cl-app
38 error command failed
39 error signal SIGTERM
40 error command sh -c node ./bin/www
41 verbose exit 1
42 timing npm Completed in 307535ms
43 verbose code 1
44 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
44 error     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-03-28T17_05_19_156Z-debug-0.log
```

The error isn't pointing me in the right direction.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: were you able to resolve this?